# Sveltekit: Vercel Deployment Edge Function error: 500 'TypeError: l is not a function'

Tags: svelte, vercel, sveltekit

I built a simple app with SvelteKit that exposes an API calls +server.ts, which in turn makes an API call to OpenAI endpoints.   When I run with node locally, it works fine.

However, if I deploy to Vercel using runtime: edge, I end up getting a 500 error.

In the logs:

```
Function
/api/images
TypeError: l is not a function
    at (../../../../node_modules/axios/lib/core/dispatchRequest.js:58:9)
    at (../../../../node_modules/axios/lib/core/Axios.js:108:14)
    at (../../../../node_modules/axios/lib/helpers/bind.js:9:14)
    at (../../../../node_modules/openai/dist/common.js:149:21)
    at (../../../../node_modules/openai/dist/api.js:1817:114)
    at (../../../../.svelte-kit/output/server/entries/endpoints/api/images/_server.ts.js:25:21)
    at (../../../../.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:170:21)
    at (../../../../.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:2577:21)
    at (../../../../.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:2470:21)
```

The code in +server.ts:

```
import { OPENAI_KEY } from '$env/static/private'
import { type CreateImageRequest, Configuration, OpenAIApi } from 'openai'
import type { RequestHandler } from './$types'
import { json } from '@sveltejs/kit'
import type { Config } from '@sveltejs/adapter-vercel'

export const config: Config = {
    runtime: 'edge'
}

export const POST: RequestHandler = async ({ request }) => {
    console.log('starting server post')
    try {
        if (!OPENAI_KEY) {
            throw new Error('OPENAI_KEY env variable not set')
        }

        const requestData = await request.json()

        if (!requestData) {
            throw new Error('No request data')
        }
        const configuration = new Configuration({
            apiKey: OPENAI_KEY,
        });
        const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration)

        const prompt: CreateImageRequest = {
            prompt: requestData.prompt,
            n: requestData.n,
            size: requestData.size,
        }

        const response = await openai.createImage(prompt)

        const image_url = response.data.data[0].url;
        const imageJson = JSON.stringify({ url: image_url })

        return new Response(imageJson, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/json'
            }
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return json({ error: 'There was an error processing your request' }, { status: 500 })
    }
}
```

I verified that the OPENAI_KEY is present in the environment.  I have another API endpoint using it successfully in the same project.

Looking for any tips on debugging this.